# Remove first and last 2 columns from DataRow

Tags: c#

I want to remove the first 2 and last 2 columns from row, I am able to remove first 2 columns by the following line :

```
IEnumerable<object> fields = row.ItemArray.Skip(2);
```

But I need to remove last 2 columns as well, please see the below whole code and advise:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<object> fields = row.ItemArray.Skip(2);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Desktop\test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not remove, it **skips** the first 2 items in array. So `skip` could accompany with `take` as below to get first from and last to:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    var from = 2;
    var to = 2;
    IEnumerable<object> fields = row.ItemArray.Skip(from).Take(row.ItemArray.Length - from - to);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Desktop\test.csv", sb.ToString());
```